# seconds since the epoch for non-Unix platforms in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Module **Unix** contains the **time**  function to get the seconds since the Epoch but is there a platform-independent way to get the same value and ensure the code compiles in non-Unix deployments ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite its name, [Unix module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html) is also [available on Windows and other platforms](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual035.html). You're safe to use `Unix.time()` for platform-independent code.

Comment: The C library's `time()` function may not have the same epoch as the traditional Unix `time()` implementation (the C standard does not require it), so for better portability you may need to use `difftime()` against a known timestamp (which you can construct with `mktime`).

Comment: The OCaml function `Unix.time()` is defined to return "the current time since 00:00:00 GMT, Jan. 1, 1970, in seconds."  So it's not dependent on the C `time()` function.  Note that `Unix.time()` returns a float value, by the way.